# android drawerLayout (SlideMenu) without scrollbar

Tags: android, android-navigationview

i have an android app with an sidemenu (the default android activity Navigation Drawer Activity)

i would like to hide the scrollbars.
i use this code for that:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    navigationView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

But the scrollbars aren't hidden.
why not?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="x.Overview">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/page_adapter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:menu="@menu/sidebar"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: is that solved?

Answer (score 3):

You can set transparent color to scrollbar by using following code in your theme style.

```
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/transparent</item>
```

and than add custom theme to your navigation view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/YOUR.THEME"
         />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this way it will work

```
private void disableNavigationViewScrollbars(NavigationView navigationView) {
    if (navigationView != null) {
        NavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
        if (navigationMenuView != null) {
            navigationMenuView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here it is - see new answer

Comment: just try with height wrapcontent

Comment: with height wrap_content the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96228/discussion-between-lakhan-and-ghost108).